# How can I trigger existing inspections on custom functions with the same signature as the inspection ones?

Tags: clion

I've written a `printf` wrapper in C.

```
void cPrintf(const char * format,  ...) {
    char * newfmt = malloc(strlen(format) * 2 + 10);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf(newfmt, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    curseDebug(newfmt);
    free(newfmt);
}
```

It takes the same arguments as `printf`, can I modify the `Format Specifiers` inspection to apply to this function as well?

```
cPrintf("Pressing %d down", s->key); 
// Currently Clion doesn't know that this is a format function
```

Comment: Whoops, meant Clion.  I figure this question is a general question related to inspections in all JetBrains IDEs.  Am I allowed to ask Clion questions in the intellij tag?

Comment: This should go as a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP. Related requests: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7200
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1005. It's specific to CLion inspection, so it doesn't make sense to use `#intellij-idea` tag.